# Exchange Server CAS Error 401 (Failed to authenticate to the second CAS)

Tags: proxy, exchange-server, kerberos, outlook-web-app

I am experiencing the issue above with our current exchange infrastructure.

We have 2 internet facing exchange sites and one non-internet facing site.

All servers have the CAS & Mailbox roles installed and are running Exchange Server 2007 RU13. The users on the non-internet facing server were previously able to use OWA without any issues as there request would be proxied via either of the internet facing servers. However, after updating our certificates to keep them up to date with the new rules whereby only a FQDN can be used we have been experiencing this issue.

Both internet facing sites work using FQDN names internally and externally.

Our hostnames where previously for example:

```
Public Site 1: Ext: mail.sitea.com and Int: ex2007-sitea.local
Public Site 2: Ext: mail.siteb.com and Int: ex2007-siteb.local
Non-Public Site 3: Ext: $null and Int: ex2007-sitec.local
```

They have been updated to the below for the new cert:

```
Public Site 1: Ext: mail.sitea.com and Int: mail.sitea.com
Public Site 2: Ext: mail.siteb.com and Int: mail.siteb.com
Non-Public Site 3: Ext: $null and Int mail.sitec.com
```

We also created a split DNS with the appropriate internal address records for each of the new internal hostnames.

Upon further investigation I can see that the CAS proxy issue is down to the kerberos authentication between the public CAS site and the internal only CAS site and I have tried to resolve this by adding in the appropriate SPN records for the non-public site.

This solves the issue, but only for 15 minutes as the created SPN records disappear for some unknown reason. I have enabled AD audit logging and can see that when I create the record it is logged in event logs however I cannot see any delete function/log record occurring and any of the DC's.

The below SPN command fixes the CAS:

```
setspn -A HOST/mail.sitec.com ex2007-sitec
```

however after 15 mins it is deleted some how and the CAS no longer authenticates.

I have run the following SPN commands:

```
setspn -A exchangeMDB/mail.sitec.com ex2007-sitec
setspn -A exchangeRFR/mail.sitec.com ex2007-sitec
setspn -A exchangeAB/mail.sitec.com ex2007-sitec
```

This also fixes the CAS authentication issue, however the exchangeAB record is deleted (while the other 2 remain) and the case proxy is broken again.

Note: All active sync functionality is working for mobile devices to the non-internet facing CAS. We are only having issues with OWA.

Any help with this would be appreciated, we are about to upgrade our systems to Ex2013 however I would like to get to the bottom of this first - Also, I am unsure as to the best approach in setting the hostnames on our new exchange servers on the local domain due to these problems. I would like to avoid having to rename the domain to a FQDN as opposed to the current .local domain name but if I cannot resolve this issue then I see no other option...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've solved this one myself so for the benefit of anyone that experiences the same issue the fix for me was:

```
setspn -A HTTP/mail.sitec.com ex2007-sitec
```

This allows all of the site-site proxy requests to authenticate successfully with Kerberos.